# How to create a new object from a model that has Interface instance injected?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to understand how this works. I have this model:

```
namespace App;

use L5SimpleFM\FileMakerModels\BaseModel;
use L5SimpleFM\Contracts\FileMakerInterface;


class FMNationality extends BaseModel
{
    protected $connection = 'filemaker';
    protected $layoutName = 'Web : Nationalities';
}
```

And BaseModel __constructor method looks like this:

```
namespace L5SimpleFM\FileMakerModels;
use L5SimpleFM\Contracts\FileMakerInterface;  

abstract class BaseModel
    {

        protected $layoutName;
        protected $connection;

        public function __construct(FileMakerInterface $fm)
        {
            $this->connection = $fm->setLayout($this->layoutName);
        }
        ...
    }
```

And FileMakerInterface inteface looks like this:

```
namespace L5SimpleFM\Contracts;

interface FileMakerInterface
{

    public function setLayout($layoutName);

    public function findAll();

    public function findByFields($fieldValues);

    ...
}
```

Now, how would I create a new FMNationality model? When I try `$x = new FMNationality();` in tinker, it asks for parameters, as BaseModel has an instance of the interface as a parameter...

All I want is to be able to create new class object and I have no idea how.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not declared a constructor, making $ x = new FMNationality () calls the inherited baseModel constructor.
So either you have to pass the parameters in your call, or you have to declare a constructor without parameters in your FMNationality class.
Something like that :)

Comment: No... that's not it.

Comment: that's exactly how @pepstille described, `$x = new FMNationality (new FileMaker)` and `class FileMaker implements FileMakerInterface{...}` would work. You may then manage your dependencies using a [service container](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/container)